# How to define/change baseurl in config for magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, base-url

For magento 1.x we could create `/app/etc/local.xml` and define something like following:

```
<stores>
        <default>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://new.magento/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
        <secure>
                    <base_url>http://new.magento/</base_url>
                </secure>
        </web>
        </default>
        <admin>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://new.magento/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
        <secure>
                    <base_url>http://new.magento/</base_url>
                </secure>
        </web>
        </admin>
    </stores>
```

I can't seem to find how to do that for Magento 2.0 CE. Why is this needed? This is for the dev setup that we are sharing right now. If we could have a common database, svn would have been a lot easier to maintain.

**Further explanation:**
What I am trying to do is to override the secure and unsecure base_urls set inside `core_config_data` table. This is to allow every dev machine to have the same database and use the same svn repository without having to worry about product uploads, orders, migrations and all other upgrade stuffs.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? If yes please suggest the solution.

Comment: No! You just simply can't... :)

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Comment: How can u b sure about anything in m2? Lol. No questions that i have asked in m2 have been answered till date btw.. so.. there might possibly be way.. plz share the question to those who can.

Comment: cool. but if you can do something on M1 than you should achieve same thing on M2 too. Just need to figure out how. If I will i will sure share it with you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry Andy I didn't :( Luckily, I am not a magento developer anymore ^_^ It's a nightmare!

Comment: I just figured it out, I'll post an answer as it might help future Googlers like me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the base url values per environment using environment variables. Edit the `app/etc/env.php` file and include the following at the top of the file:

```
$_ENV['CONFIG__DEFAULT__WEB__SECURE__BASE_URL'] = 'http://example.localhost/magento-website-path';
$_ENV['CONFIG__DEFAULT__WEB__UNSECURE__BASE_URL'] = 'http://example.localhost/magento-website-path';
```

Then flush magento cache on the command line with:

```
$ bin/magento cache:flush
```

More information on overriding configuration values with environment variables can be found in the [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-var-name.html)

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that executing one or a combination of `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade` can sometimes remove these additions from the `env.php` file.

To get around this I have created a `.env` file in the project's root directory which I load using [symfony/dotenv](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv):

1) Add the package to your project's dependencies:

```
composer require symfony/dotenv
```

2) Create the .env file so it looks like:

```
CONFIG__DEFAULT__WEB__SECURE__BASE_URL='http://example.localhost/magento-website-path'
CONFIG__DEFAULT__WEB__UNSECURE__BASE_URL='http://example.localhost/magento-website-path'
```

3) Create `app/dotenv.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php

$dotenv = new \Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv();

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../.env')) {
    $dotenv->load(__DIR__ . '/../.env');
}
```

4) Add this file to the project's composer.json autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/dotenv.php"
    ]
}
```

5) Finally, dump composer's autoload file:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this Magento component for ease of use based on symfony/dotenv: https://github.com/zepgram/magento-dotenv.
It does all steps described by [@Andy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/60048/andy) in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

U can find this in **Store**->**Configuration**->**General**->**Web**->**Base URLs**

Comment: Please read my question again. I am trying to have a seperate base_url path among all the test setups in different machines, but have a common database for all setups. Basically trying to override the baseurls set inside `core_config_data`, which is what you just mentioned.